Не запускается приложение на Ubuntu [WSL]
Друг скомпилировал мод для HL2 на линукс, и скинул мне его протестить, я пытаюсь запустить через WSL и мне выдает ошибку:
error while loading shared libraries: libasan.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
я установил все libasan что выдало в apt search ( там был только 5 и 6 ) но все равно ниче не сработало.

Компиляция и запуск должны проводиться на одной и той же версии дистрибутива, а у вас значит версии оказались разные

Выполните команду readelf -d <приложение> | grep NEEDED и посмотрите на имена библиотек. В вашей системе должны быть файлы с точно такими же именами. Какой у вас дистрибутив в WSL? Есть два варианта: найти пакет с файлом libasan.so.8 для вашего дистрибутива, либо же собрать libasan из исходников. Ну или поставьте в WSL Ubuntu 22 / 24. Там точно есть libasan8
